# Cannot shut off SweaveOpts Concordance = True

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

**UPDATE**

**SweaveOpts are now shut off and the macro is no longer auto populating, but I still cannot get my plot into the document**

I am using R-Studio, the latest version on my laptop and my desktop. All my packages are up-to-date as of this morning. I am trying to on my laptop insert a plot into a pdf. I am using `knitr` and `pdfLatex`, the global options in R-Studio are set to knitr and pdfLatex, the same as on my desktop.

When trying this on my laptop the following always appears in my `.Rnw` file:

`\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}`

which is preventing me from rendering my pdf the way I want, meaning my plots do not show inside the document but as a separate file.  I ensured I have exactly the same settings in R-studio on the laptop and desktop, I am using the same exact version of R in each 3.1.3 and the same exact packages to produce the document `knitr` and `ggplot2`

I am completely baffled on how to shut `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` off and make it stay off.

The head of the document on my desktop looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{titepage}
     \begin{center}
 ...
```

And on my laptop for a different document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{title}
    \begin{center}
...
```

I did get rid of the `\usepackage{setspace}` line just to see if that was the issue and it was not.

I have also noticed that when I insert a code chunk and start to type options inside of it, like `fig.align='center'` the autocomplete works on the desktop but not the laptop, almost like it does not recognize that the `knitr` library is loaded.

Comment: If you meant to use knitr instead of Sweave, choose the option knitr instead of Sweave in the `Tools -> Global Options`. This has confused quite a few users, but I'm not sure if we (RStudio) should just change the default option to knitr.

Comment: Hi Yihui I do ind Ed have knitr set as the default in my global settings. I ended up making a new folder, a new project and a new .Rnw file and that seemed to do it, maybe there was something funky going on with the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the menu

```
Tools ->  Global Options -> Sweave
```

and unselect *Always enable Rnw concordance (required for Synctex)* which should take care of it.

Comment: No graph...also I have that optioned check off on my desktop machine and graphs produce from there fine. All settings were equal between machines in R-Studio - perplexing

Comment: Maybe start out with a fresh document: _File -> New File -> Sweave Document_  I can assure that this does not place a the concordance macro into the generated tex file on my box.

Comment: That worked on my laptop, I will create a new file and dump in my stuff in there and see if that works.

Comment: so I created a new document and placed the contents of the old one into the new one and still not plots....I have not even finished my morning coffee...

Comment: Given that, I think it must be something in my document

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted as that did infact shut the macro off, yet I still cannot for the life of me get my plots in this particular document, it's really nothing fancy either.

Comment: I ended up making a new folder, a new project and not useing the `setspace` package and now everything seems to magically work...

Comment: your problem was that you had "Sweave" instead of knitr in the project options (changing the global options after that doesnt change it in once created projects).